# Is there a way to enforce "one of theses inputs but not all are required" for Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing a function that updates one of three possible fields in Django--either a boolean, a string, or an integer.

I attempted to to it this way:

```py
class AccountsForm(forms.Form): 
    update_key = forms.CharField(required=True)
    update_value  = forms.ComboField(fields=[forms.CharField(),
         forms.IntegerField(), forms.BooleanField()], 
         required=True)
```

But this is not the functionality I'm looking for, as it expects a combination of a CharField+IntegerField+BooleanField. I need at exactly one of the three fields to be present in the form. Is this possible with django forms?

Comment: Use three separate fields (all with `required=False`) and write a custom `clean()` method on your form to validate the data. Since the form's `clean()` method is called after each individual clean, you can know for sure that the input of each field is already validated. Then just check which ones are filled and which not by looking at the values of `cleaned_data`.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) actually show you how to do that:

- Use three separate fields
- Make all of them not required (`required=False`)
- Add a `clean()` method to your form where you validate the three fields together. If you first call `super().clean()`, you can be sure that the fields have been validated separately first, e.g. that the input to the `IntegerField` is actually an integer, so you don't need to do that anymore.
- Use the `cleaned_data` dictionary to look at the values for each field. You could also check `self.errors[<field>]` to see if any of the fields was filled in incorrectly.
- Raise a `ValidationError` is you're not happy with the input.
- In your template, don't forget to display the `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` at the top of your form so the user knows the error you're raising. Or just add the error on specifically one of the fields to display it close to the field.

Comment: Attemtping to do this, but can't seem to figure out how to check whether there isn't exactly one inputted. It seems that `super().clean()` will return a dictionary with empty inputs set to `''` if it's a string and `False` if boolean

Comment: ah, you need to use a [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#nullbooleanfield) if you want to distinguish empty from False (then check with `is None` rather than `not <field>`). And `''` means empty, right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm concerned for situations when a user might expressly want to set notes to `''` .  If I treat `''` as "user did not input a value into this field" then it might cause problems ?  Thank you for the `NullBooleanField` tip!!!

Comment: Mmm I realized the `update_key` makes the `''` problem a nonissue. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: But empty string is the only empty value for a `CharField`. You can't distinguish "no input" from empty string. It contradicts your requirement that at least one of the fields must have a value.